# ajax jquery not working

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have written below code to make an ajax call using jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'verify.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'mobile': 'update'

    }
    success: function(response) {
        if (response == 'success') {
            $('#popupscreen').fadeOut('slow');
        }
        else {
            $("#error").html("<p>" + Registration failed! Please try again. + "</p>").show();
        }
    }
});
```

I am getting error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** in line **success : function(response){**
Why I am getting this error?

Comment: `$("#error").html("<p> Registration failed! Please try again </p>").show();`

Comment: If initial code formattig you had in your question is the same as you have it in your IDE, than you should think about learning some code formatting rules. It will help you (and others) reading your own code a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a comma:

```
type : 'POST',
data : { 
    'mobile' : 'update'

}, //<---- there should be a comma here
success : function(response){
     if(response == 'success')
     {
```

Also some quotes:

```
$("#error").html("<p>Registration failed!Please try again.</p>").show();
```

Answer (score 5):

because you're missing a comma after the closing brace for data.

your code should look more like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'verify.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'mobile': 'update'},
    success: function(response) {
        if (response == 'success') {
            $('#popupscreen').fadeOut('slow');
        }
        else {
            $("#error").html("<p>" + 'Registration failed!Please try again.' + "</p>").show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mike and @undefined . There were two errors. Its working now

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma right before your "success":

```
    data : { 
        'mobile' : 'update'
    },
```